# MySQL database design: One user table, two user groups?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a tourism platform and I am planning to have the following users table:

> **USERS**: id, username, password, email, first_name, last_name, description, picture_path

My goal is to have two groups of users:

1. tour operators
2. tourists

When a tour operator logs in, I want the system to recognize that he is from the group "tour operators" so that different information is going to be displayed him as if he was part of the "tourists" group.

My question: What is the best way to realize these two user groups in my database design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have `UserCategories` table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `UserCategories` (
    UC_ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    IC_Title VARCHAR(100)
 )engine=innodb;
```

Then in your users table have a column called `CategoryID` and have it reference `UserCategories` table on `UC_ID = CategoryID`.

This way you will know which category user belongs to whether its `operator` ID 1 or `tourist` ID 2.

The way I would do it is I would have another table call it `Permissions` that references Permission to UserCategories. That way you will be able to customize what kind of access `Tourists` should have.

**Update:**

```
   SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 ...
   FROM users
   INNER JOIN UserCategories ON UC_ID = CategoryID
   INNER JOIN Permissions ON UC_ID = PCategoryID
   WHERE Permission = 'update_data' OR Permission = 'delete_data'
```

Or you could grab all permissions for a specific user category and see if currently logged in user has that permission to perform that action.

Comment: So you suggest three separate tables: 1.) Users, 2.) UserCategories, 3.) Permissions. What would be the SQL command for linking my users table with the usercategories table?

Answer (score 0):

An easy method of doing this would be to add a column to your USERS table which store the type of the group. For example: `groupType`  could store either `operator` or `tourist` and depending on that value, you can show or hide stuff in your page.